# Problems with positioning css html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a header on my page, but say for example i have two divs, which ever div is declared first will appear on top, and the second div wil appear below it. regardless of what position i set for it. Could anyone help me please?

```
css;

    body 
{
    background-color:#CCC;
}

#pageHeader{
    position:relative;
    width:900px;
    height:94px;
    background-color:White;
    margin:0 auto;

}

    #nhsLogo
{
        position:relative;
        margin-left:40px;
}


    #openingHours
{
        position:relative;
        margin-left:500px;
        top:0px;

}
```

Html:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Template.master.cs" Inherits="Template.Template" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />     
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" />  
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pageHeader">  

      <div id="openingHours">
    <p style="color:Green; font-size:18px; font-style:oblique;">0876 890756</p>
    <p style="color:Purple; font-size:18px; font-style:oblique;">Opening hours</p> <p></p>
    </div>

    <div id="nhsLogo">
    <p><img src="img/high.png" alt="GPlus logo" /></p>   
    </div>



    </div>


    <form id="form1" runat="server">



    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript"  src='<%# ResolveUrl ("~/Js/jquery-1.2.3.min.js") %>'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to have two divs side-by-side, is to given them "float" CSS rules:

```
float:left;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

alernatively you can use absolute positioning.

give your body the css rule: `position:relative;`

then any children elements of body that you want to position, give the css rules:

```
position:absolute;
top: 10px; //change this value to adjust vertical positioning
left: 10px; //change this value to adjust horizontal positioning
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Hmmm that solved one part of it, but i have updated my question with an image of how it looks. The problem is, is that the x position can be changed fine. But i cant change the Y position of the image, it is always there. I want to be able to move that up, but if the div containing the image is the second one declared the Y position is moved to there?

Comment: any divs that have position:absolute and then some top and left values, are positioned relative to the parent div that has position:relative;

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct (click the big tick at the top left corner of my answer). Glad i could help.